# decoding instance_name in sys.dm_os_performance_counters on Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure-sql-database, perfmon

doing some work with the SQL Perfmon counters and banging my head against the wall trying to work out how to translate the instance_name column to a database name.
So if I run a query like the following

```
SELECT top 10 left(counter_name, 25), left(instance_name,40), cntr_value
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters 
WHERE counter_name = 'Log Bytes Received/sec'
```

I get a resultset like

Log Bytes Received/sec      _Total                                      0

Log Bytes Received/sec      100f6a49-cd58-432a-8680-ed0f1069c5ea        0

Log Bytes Received/sec      dd7b88c8-43c4-48a8-bf97-e174bb5c5eca        0

Log Bytes Received/sec      7a0dc4f3-b236-4c0f-b42c-357bfd521b16        0

Log Bytes Received/sec      5d527545-4bcc-4c66-b315-e1f8fc653245        0

How do I translate the value of instance_name (100f6a49-cd58-432a-8680-ed0f1069c5ea) to a database_name
I thought I could look in sys.databases but no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ran into the same problem today but on Azure SQL Database Managed Instance
this works

select service_broker_guid FROM sys.databases

Answer (score 3):

That GUID actually ties back to the `physical_database_name` column in `sys.databases`.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-databases-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> For SQL Server, the physical name of the database. For Azure SQL Database, a common id for the databases on a server.

However, looking at that column on my own Azure SQL DB, the behavior is a little surprising to me. I created two SQL DBs on the same server.

If I connect to `master` and run the query:

```sql
SELECT name, physical_database_name
FROM sys.databases;
```

All three rows in the results (master + the two databases) have the same `physical_database_name` (6dfa05ee-9c60-4288-a344-11f9f1459dcc):

[image: SSMS Results1]

When I connect to a specific user database, that GUID changes, based on which database I am connected to. (Also, you cannot see the user databases that you are not connected to. That part is expected!)

[image: SSMS Results 2]
[image: SSMS Results 3]

I'm not sure why that column populates based on the current database context, and not based on the row. That is awfully confusing, if you ask me.

So, to correlate that GUID from `sys.dm_os_performance_counters` back to a specific database, you'll need to connect to each database, query the `physical_database_name` from `sys.databases` and then match up all those separate result sets from the separate databases to map GUID to a name.

Comment: Ok - what I didn’t mention was I was running my query on the read only secondary of the georeplica - Which must be why the guids don’t correlate. Will retry on the primary

Comment: Yes retried on the primary and it "works" as you described there - still not very helpful. Can't understand what is going on on the secondary at all. Will try working with the Total row in perfmon and ignore the rest.